# Загрузить контент страницы через Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно загрузить статью на сайт с помощью Ajax, в инете есть следующий пример:
Создадим 3 файла.
index.html

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.7.0/d3.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='ajax.js'></script>
   </head>

   <body>
   Какой-то контент...
    <br/>Какой-то контент...
   <br/>блок вывода с AJAX:
   <br/>
   <div id="blockajax"></div>
   <br/>блок вывода с AJAX:

   </body>
   </html>
```

ajax.js

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
  $("#blockajax").load("text-dlya-ajax.html");
})
})(jQuery)
```

text-dlua-ajax.html

```
Этот <b>текст</b> будет выведен через <b>AJAX</b>
```

Но данный пример не работает, возможно кто-то подскажет в чем дело. Сайт находиться локально на компе

Comment: Вы запускаете его в веб-сервере или просто открыли index.html в браузере? Какие ошибки в консоли падают?

Comment: какой локальный сервер у Вас?

Comment: @Ofer просто index.html в браузере

Comment: AJAX запросы не обрабатываются, если вы просто открыли html файл в браузере через проводник. Вы должны поднять любой вебсервер и тогда пример заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте запрос на backend с идентификатором статьи, найдите её в бд, сформируйте представление(view) и сделайте append в блок. Пример ниже

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "your-backend-url",
  data: { id: your-article-id}
  success: function(response) {
      //response is rendered view
     $('#your-block-id-where-to-render').append(response);
  }
})
```

В Вашем случае:

```
var html = $.get("text-dlya-ajax.html", function(data){
    $(this).children("div:first").html(data);
});

$("#blockajax").append(html);
```